# transaction, mysql INSERT not working

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

Trying to create a simple transaction in which data gets inserted into mysql database. The code runs smoothly except nothing gets inserted into the database:

```
$db->beginTransaction();

$singleadd = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO games VALUES (:seller, :cardset, :card, :quantity, :quality, :price)");
$singleadd->bindParam(':type',    $type,    PDO::PARAM_STR);
$singleadd->bindParam(':gameset', $gameset, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$singleadd->bindParam(':game',    $game,    PDO::PARAM_STR);
$singleadd->bindParam(':quantity',$quantity,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$singleadd->bindParam(':quality', $quality, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$singleadd->bindParam(':price',   $price,   PDO::PARAM_INT);

try {
    $singleadd->execute(); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $db = null;
    exit();
}
```

All of the data is properly defined. When I submit the form I get no errors, but when i check my database no data is added...

Comment: Do you ever call `$db->commit()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your named placeholders are not defined in your `bindParam` statements.

In your sql you have:

`(:seller, :cardset, :card, :quantity, :quality, :price)`

and in your `bindParam` statements you have:

`:type, :gameset, :game, :quantity, :quality, :price`

notice that `seller`, `card` and `cardset` are not defined....

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps specify which columns you're inserting the data into?

`prepare("INSERT INTO games (col1, col2, col3, etc) VALUES (v1, v2, v3, etc)");`